# return does not seem to update its condition

Tags: ruby, return

I'm trying to validate a selection before proceeding with my program, and am trying to do it as below, calling one method within another if the `select` variable does not meet certain conditions.

My problem is `return if select == 9` doesn't seem to return if select is changed to 9. Is there any way of re-evaluating this after I re-enter the `select` method? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

```
def select (select)
  return if select == 9
  invalid_select(select) if !valid_select?(select)
  puts "And how many would you like?" 
  # [etc.....]
end

def invalid_select (select)
  puts "Please enter a valid select, between 1 and 5. 9 completes your order."
  select = gets.chomp.to_i
  select (select)
end
```

**Edit** I've since changed the above to:

```
def select (choice)
  return if choice == 9
  invalid_selection(choice) if !valid_selection?(choice)
  puts "And how many would you like?"
  quant = gets.chomp.to_i
  # [etc.........]
end

def invalid_selection(choice)
  puts "Please enter a valid selection, between 1 and 5. 9 completes your order."
  choice = gets.chomp.to_i
  return if choice == 9
  select (choice)
end

def valid_selection?(choice)
  is_a_number?(choice) && choice > 0 && choice < 6 || choice == 9
end
```

And am still getting nowhere.

Comment: you are sure that `select.class == Integer`?

Comment: You are using `select` as a method and a local variable. Expect a trouble with this.

Comment: I believe select.class has to be an Integer as select = gets.chomp.to_i, I'll try changing the variable name but I don't think that would be causing the problem?

Comment: @BonoboUK if `return if select == 9` actually calls `select` method instead of using variable, than it is. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse Why not posting an answer ? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I am not sure whether it is an answer. + Answer should also contain why it should be refactored so it doesn't create infinite call stack. And I am leaving right now. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse Yeah... true..

Comment: I thought using an infinite loop with a "return if selection ==" was a good way to implement a menu? I've changed the variable name with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @BroiSatse that can't be the problem, because the method takes 1 argument, so when you call just `select == 9`, if Ruby tried to use method, and `ArgumentError` would be raised.

Comment: @arnvald indeed, if you enter 9 it simply confirms it's a valid choice, and re-enters the select (choice) method, doing nothing for the first 2 lines (despite select equalling 9), kicking in at 'puts "And how many would you like?"'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you recursively call `select` method. So if I provide wrong input you call it inside the `invalid_selection` method, and then if I provide wrong input again, you call it again inside. So when I finally I provide 9 as an input, the most internal `select` call indeed returns on the correct line, but we're already inside a few calls of this method, so we go back to the previous calls and there we execute the lines after calling `invalid_selection`

Anyway, the example script running menu is here:

```
def invalid_select?(select)
  select <= 0 || select > 10
end

def run_menu
  loop do
    input = gets.chomp.to_i
    return if input == 9
    if invalid_select?(input)
      print "Please enter a valid select, between 1 and 5. 9 completes your order.\n"
      redo                                                                               
    end
  end
  #here go the correct options
end

run_menu
```

`loop` is an infinite loop, it goes again and again until `return` or `break` is called. So now what happens:
 - if you provide 9, it will just terminate execution
 - if you provide wrong argument, it will put the message on the screen and call `redo` which goes back to beginning of the loop
 - if you provide correct input, the code after validation will be called

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer - as you said the problem was losing the variable by calling it recursively, thanks again!